# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens: Add additonal claims

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

### **Background**

For authn/z purposes we are creating JWT Tokens by using [JOSE-JWT](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt). This token are passed via **Authorize: Bearer** HTTP header to different microservces to impersonate the caller.

The microservices itself leverage **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens** in order to validate the JWT Tokens:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

// The key length needs to be of sufficient length, or otherwise an error will occur.
var tokenSecretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenSecretKey"]);

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    // Token signature will be verified using a private key.
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenSecretKey),

    // Token will only be valid if contains "accelist.com" for "iss" claim.
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = "accelist.com",

    // Token will only be valid if contains "accelist.com" for "aud" claim.
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = "accelist.com",

    // Token will only be valid if not expired yet, with 5 minutes clock skew.
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),

    ValidateActor = false,
};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
});
```

Certain JWT reserved claims will be automatically be populated into **HttpContext.User**, i.e.

[image]

---

### **Question**

Is there are a simple and elegant way to populate **additional custom** claims into **HttpContext.User**? Currently the only way I can think of, is to decode the token and call **HttpContext.User.Claims.Add(...)**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Fabe, did you try the approach in my answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of decoding the token and adding your `custom claims`, you'd do a `Union` of both `user` and `custom` claims on the fly like:

```
private async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GetJwtSecurityToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            //Get the user claims
            var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
            //Merge the claims here
            return new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "", //Insert your issuer
                audience: "",//Insert your audience
                claims: GetTokenClaims(user).Union(userClaims), //This is the Union you need
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),//Add expiry time here
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(IssuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)//Do your magic here
            );
        }
```

The `GetTokenClaims()` method will just return a list of custom claims like:

```
private static IEnumerable<Claim> GetTokenClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    return new List<Claim>
        {
        new Claim("UserName", user.UserName),
        new Claim("Email", user.Email),
        new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName),
        new Claim("LastName", user.LastName),
        new Claim("Phone", user.PhoneNumber),
        //More custom claims
        };
}
```

And finally, you can wrap it up as follows:

```
//Get the token combination
var token = await GetJwtSecurityToken(user);
//Write and return the token
return Ok(new
{
    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
    expiration = token.ValidTo,              
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! This is not exactly what I meant. You are describing how to add additional claims to an existing token. I already added existing claims to a JWT token. When a client receives the token, some of the JWT claims are automatically populated into HttpContext.User, but when I try to access other JWT claims null is returned. Sorry for not being so clear. I will update my question.